# Port is closed for outside connections

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, docker

I have an instance with docker. One docker container listens for 9017 port but it is not available by public ip. I disabled ufw and cleared iptables.

```
root@docker-1gb-fra1-01:/home# ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
root@docker-1gb-fra1-01:/home# ufw status
Status: inactive
root@docker-1gb-fra1-01:/home# iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
root@docker-1gb-fra1-01:/home# iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

nmap shows

```
root@docker-1gb-fra1-01:~# nmap -p 9017 139.59.213.99

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-11-25 16:55 UTC
Nmap scan report for 139.59.213.99
Host is up.
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
9017/tcp filtered unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.17 seconds
root@docker-1gb-fra1-01:~# nmap -p 9017 localhost

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-11-25 16:55 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00013s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
9017/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.26 seconds
```

netstat output

```
root@docker-1gb-fra1-01:~# netstat -ntple
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          15869       1309/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::9017                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          18314       1935/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::9403                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          18807       2121/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::9404                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          18726       2095/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::9451                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          18577       2050/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          15879       1309/sshd
```

I thought the problem that port listened on ipv6 so I set "net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1" in /etc/sysctl.conf but it doesn't help.

any idea why 9017 port is not available outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason - bad port forwarding configuration in local network. So actually port wasn't accessible only from my local network.